# Pixel Size Different Than Grid Cell Size - Photoshop Pixel Art

Tags: pixel, photoshop

I was trying to learn pixel art using Photoshop and following different tutorials available in the internet.

For Pixel Art drawing, most important thing is to setup grid structure so we can draw easily for easy pixel.

Now if you check my attached image then you will notice that my pixel size not matching with grid cell size though I have set pencil size as 1.
So one pixel size needs to be similar as per grid single cell size.

[image]

As per my understanding, I can say that there is some mistake in Gridline settings.
Please suggest me some correction for this, if you got my point.

I want to create grid lines exact similar to one pixel size.

Comment: You know this isn't a coding question, but use the Pixel Grid instead (View, Show <pixel Grid>)

Comment: Yes I knew this is not coding related question but Photoshop tag exist so asked this question. I don't want to use Pixel Grid, I just want to setup this Grid because it has multiple options.